# A way to set field validation attribute in pydantic

Tags: python, validation, jsonschema, python-dataclasses, pydantic

I have the following pydentic dataclass

```py
@dataclass
class LocationPolygon:
    type: int
    coordinates: list[list[list[float]]]
```

this is taken from a json schema where the most inner array has `maxItems=2, minItems=2`.
I couldn't find a way to set a validation for this in pydantic.
setting this in the field is working only on the outer level of the list.

```py
@dataclass
class LocationPolygon:
    type: int
    coordinates: list[list[list[float]]] = Field(maxItems=2, minItems=2)
```

using `@validator` and updating the field attribute doesn't help either as the value was already set  and basic validations were already made:

```py
@validator('coordinates')
    def coordinates_come_in_pair(cls, values, field):
        field.sub_fields[0].sub_fields[0].field_info.min_items = 2
        field.sub_fields[0].sub_fields[0].field_info.max_items = 2
```

I thought about using `root_validator` with `pre=True`, but there are only the raw values there.

Is there a way to tweak the field validation attributes or use pydantic basic rules to make that validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`conlist`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-conlist) function to create nested constrained list:

```
from pydantic import conlist
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class LocationPolygon:
    type: int
    coordinates: list[list[conlist(float, min_length=2, max_length=2)]]
```

Comment: `conlist` doesn't have these parameters listed in their docs.  https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.conlist

Comment: found this in their docs

> max_items = extra.pop('max_items', None)  # type: ignore
    if max_items is not None:
        warn('`max_items` is deprecated and will be removed, use `max_length` instead', DeprecationWarning)
        if max_length in (None, _Unset):
            max_length = max_items  # type: ignore

Answer (score 1):

There is an update in the argument name for [conlist](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.conlist:%7E:text=%2C%0A%20%20%20%20*%2C-,min_length,-%3DNone%2C). This should work now.

```
    from pydantic import conlist
    from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
    
    
    @dataclass
    class LocationPolygon:
        type: int
        coordinates: list[list[conlist(float, min_length=2, max_length=2)]]
```